# SeekBar setThumb(null) crashes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget, seekbar

So I have a SeekBar that fills up while a file is downloading. Once it is done downloading the filled SeekBar goes away. I run the method setThumb(null) to make it fill up instead of just showing a thumb icon go across. Well now with the newer OS this method crashes the program with a NullPointerException. I set it to an actual drawable but it fills up half the bar at start which I don't want. When I don't set a thumb at all it shows an ugly little thing go across. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to solve this is turning it into a ProgressBar (thanks to Romain Guy and MH) and then to change style things about it. This website basically explains it and is very helpful: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things:

- Use a [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), not a `SeekBar`
- Set the thumb drawable to be a transparent drawable ([`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#transparent) or a transparent image)

Comment: Well I did realize to use ProgressBar since that's what it is. But now it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: You can set the progress bar's style to horizontal.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Well when you said style horizontal I thought of android:orientation="horizontal" but I figured it out thanks to your tip.